# How to run a spec with multiple sets of data?

Tags: ruby, rspec, data-driven-tests

I'm using Ruby, RSpec, Watir, etc. I'm a newbie at it. I need to run a spec with different sets of data. I used to to this in Selenium reading the data from an excel sheet or passing the data through an xml. How do I do it here?

Answer (score 0):

You can still read the data from excel or xml and save it as an instance variable in your spec file.

Using `nokogiri` gem:

```
require 'nokogiri'

RSpec.describe 'Your Feature' do
  context 'Using dataset 1', :dataset1 do
    let :data do
      File.open('dataset1.xml') { |f| Nokogiri::XML(f) }
    end

    it 'test with dataset 1' do
      # describe your test here
      puts data  # data returns a Nokogiri::XML::Document object
    end
  end

  context 'Using dataset 2', :dataset2 do
    let :data do
      File.open('dataset2.xml') { |f| Nokogiri::XML(f) }
    end

    it 'test with dataset 2' do
      # describe your test here
      puts data  # data returns a Nokogiri::XML::Document object
    end
  end
end
```

You can parse the `Nokogiri::XML::Document` that is stored in the `data` variable by using `CSS` and `XPath` queries. Read more about `nokogiri` api [here](http://www.nokogiri.org/tutorials/searching_a_xml_html_document.html).